# Как ограничить поиск локаций в RNGooglePlaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, map, геолокация

Вызываю `RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal()`, чтобы была возможность искать локацию. Но мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы можно было искать в пределах одной страны или нескольких (Дания и США). Не знаю, как это осуществить.

```
RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal().then(place => {
        this.setState({
            address: place.address,
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В соответствии с базовыми API-интерфейсами [Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder#setCountry(java.lang.String))/[iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter) вы можете ограничивать свои поисковые запросы только одной страной за раз.  Есть параметр опций в методе [**`openAutocompleteModal`**](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places#open-autocomplete-modal-eg-as-callback-to-an-onpress-event), внутри которого есть проперти `country`, куда строкой можно передать ISO код страны. К примеру ограничение по США будет выглядеть вот так:

```
RNGooglePlaces
  .openAutocompleteModal({
    country: 'US',
  })
  .then(place => {
    this.setState({
      address: place.address,
    })
})
```

Список кодов стран можно посмотреть тут: [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

Ссылки на библиотеки тут: [react-native-google-places](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places#react-native-google-places) и [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete)

Ссылка на похожий вопрос тут: [How to restrict Google places search for more than two countries in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52474945/5275890)

Согласно [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) (JavaScript API) можно попытаться фильтровать по несколькими странами, указав параметр [components](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) вот так:

```
components=country:us|country:dk
```

для запроса формата:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters
```

Но это уже совсем другая история (не совсем `RNGooglePlaces`).